# Installing Umbuntu on an old laptop

Tags: boot, system-installation

I have a very basic question.  I recently installed Umbuntu on my newish Dell laptop.  No problem; created a CD/DVD, booted from it and everything worked great.

So I tried the same process on an older laptop:  a Dell Inspiron 3800.  In this case, I have run into a series of problems.  This laptop will not boot from either the CD drive or the USB port.  I have tried the BitTorrent approach and now have a file (ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-i386.iso) and not a clue as to how to proceed.  The network approach might work if I knew what files I needed and where to put them.

How might I proceed?

Fred

Answer (score 0):

Try to constantly hit the ESC button on startup. After the BIOS screen has been shown and tries to boot the OS you should get boot options.

One of these boot options on my laptop is "General" which means USB. That way you should successfully boot your laptop from USB and you'd be able to install Ubuntu on it.

Success!

Fred Handoko